# SQL Worksheet text cursor do not show in Oracle Sql Devoloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Worksheet text cursor do not show in Oracle Sql Devoloper
Oracle Sql Devoloper Version 17.4.0.355

Comment: Are you on linux desktop?

Comment: Yes Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Comment: Known issue and workaround here https://community.oracle.com/thread/3700530

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Tools** > **Preferences** : +**Caret Behavior** : change **Caret Color** , for example red.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue in Ubuntu sql developer. I used the below command in product.conf to fix this issue.

Command : *AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true to ~/.sqldeveloper//product.conf fixed it for me.*

Answer (score 0):

I know the topic is old, but the only solution that worked for me was to change the mouse cursor system settings (I'm using windows 10).
In mouse settings and "additional mouse options" I changed the Pointers to a different scheme ("windows back large" worked for me, this will change to a thick caret)
Please note that my issue was with the mouse caret, not the caret itself, so the solution from @fdurmus77 didn't work for me.